# sqlbulkcopy, i want to overwrite current rows in the database

Tags: sql, vb.net, sql-server-2005

In my program I am populating a datatable and then bulkcopying it into my database.

However, I want it to overwrite a row in the database if 3 of the columns in the the row match.

For example if I have 5 columns

membernum
dateregistered
name
address
city
state

So if the membernum, dateregistered and name match I want to overwrite the row.
with the data from the bulk insert. In my program the entire database table is not populated and I think its to big to load it.

```
Using bcp As SqlBulkCopy = New SqlBulkCopy(SqlDataSource2.ConnectionString)

    bcp.DestinationTableName = "dbo.dashboardtasks"

    bcp.WriteToServer(table)
```

If the best method is to create a datatable with my database table how would I compare the rows and then overwrite the tables where there are matches in the particular 3 columns. and then update the database with only the rows that have either changed or the new ones

```
INSERT INTO [dashboardtasks] ([tour], [taskname], [deptdate], [tasktype], [desc], [duedate], [compdate], [comments], [agent], [compby], [graceperiod], [id])
```

Comment: How do you find a match?  Is there an ID field or a natural key?  Cuz otherwise this does not make sense.  If you have an ID field, wouldn't it always overwrite?  If there is no ID or key, then couldn't multiple rows from the external file match and overwrite multiple existing rows?

Comment: theres a primary key, but in my generated datatable no

Comment: my primary key is auto increment i think thats why it allows it to repeat

Answer (score 6, accepted):

At Mitch points out the bulk copy functions ([`SqlBulkCopy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy.aspx), [`bcp`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162802.aspx) and [`BULK INSERT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188365.aspx)) only handle inserts, not updates.

The normal approach to your problem is to perform the bulk load in two (or more) steps - first you use bulk inserts to load your data into a staging table, and then use a query to insert / update records in the main tables based on the data in the staging tables, for example:

```
INSERT INTO MyTable
(Column1, Column2, [etc...])
SELECT Column1, Column2, [etc...] 
FROM Test_Staging
WHERE [Some condition]
```

See [SQL SERVER – Insert Data From One Table to Another Table](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/08/15/sql-server-insert-data-from-one-table-to-another-table-insert-into-select-select-into-table/)  for information on how to insert into one table from another table - it is also possible to do a join in an UPDATE, but I'm struggling to find a good resource on this.

Comment: hmmm is this happening in sql server or in vb.net. because maybe if it could work in sql server it would be better

Comment: @Mitch I was writing this as you added the comment about a staging table - didn't realised you had edited your question.

Comment: if you could help me achieve this it would be appreiciated or if you know where i can find an example

Comment: sweet, thanks a lot, but i wasnt worried about the insert statement i was more thinking like, my asp.net program performs an bulkcopy into dbo.staging (for example), then how will my stored procedure run. is it possible to bulkcopy into a storedprocedure and then right away perform the task of overwriting to the real table

Comment: @MyHeadHurts I'm not sure that I follow - I think that you may be confusing concepts.  Its not possible to bulk copy records in **to** a stored procedure (a stored procedure is stored SQL / Code, not stored data).  You could execute the bulk copy in a stored procedure by using the BULK INSERT statement - is this what you mean?)

Comment: hmm my problem is, if the bulkcopy is completed into a staging table how will i get my realtable to update at the same time.

Answer (score 3):

SqlBulkCopy only does bulk INSERTS (which is just one of the reasons it's fast).

- [How Does SqlBulkCopy Deal with Duplicate Records?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/irenak/archive/2006/02/10/529553.aspx)

You will need to use a different method to do bulk updates:

- Use a staging table. Use SqlBulkCopy to load data into the staging table, then use a stored procedure to perform the merge.
- Use SSIS.
- In SQL Server 2008 there is the MERGE statement for doing this.

Comment: is it possible with a stored procedure?

Comment: to use the bulkinsert to place all the new rows in a table, using a stored procedure, and after that is done overwrite rows that match the 3 columns i want

Comment: @MyHeadHurts : yes. that's what I meant in the first alternative above.

Comment: alright well that makes me feel better as i already wrote the program, but my problem is what would a stored procedure like this look like i am fairly new at sql