# similar function SqlBulkCopy for copy data from access to sql server table

Tags: c#, winforms

.please say to me similar function SqlBulkCopy for copy data from access to sql server table.
I have access file and want copy columns to sql server table columns. SqlBulkCopy is poor for this work.

Comment: Why is `SqlBulkCopy` a poor fit for your problem? What have you tried already? Is this a regular task, or a one-off? If it's a one-off, use the Import Data wizard in SQL Server Management Studio.

Comment: SqlBulkCopy only can add columns to empty table.I want add to exsisting table where have data into table in sqlserver.

Comment: @anfd: `SqlBulkCopy` is for adding rows, not columns. According to answers to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4846676/897326), you can use SqlBulkCopy to insert to existing table. Your data will *NOT* be wiped out.

Comment: correct but again can not copy to exsisting table.

Comment: @anfd: See my updated comment. In short, you can.