# How to use SqlBulkCopy.WriteToServer to Bulk Insert rows into SQL Server , ONLY if Not Exists

Tags: c#, sql-server, bulkinsert, sqlbulkcopy

We are using SqlBulkCopy.WriteToServer to bulk insert to SQL Server and works very well. However, it fails when a record already exists. What we need is to "ignore" those rows that already exist, and insert the non-existing ones.

SqlException: Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK__Pharmacy__3214EC072C1E8537'.
Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.Pharmacy'. The duplicate key value is (797cba76-8bbd-4dbd-a360-4f8e8a6ef85b)

How can we use SqlBulkCopy.WriteToServer to insert rows, if they do not exist, without breaking or failing.

```
try
{
    // Write from the source to the destination.
    bulkCopy.WriteToServer(dt);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    throw new Exception($"BulkInject error in {dt.TableName}", ex);
}
```

**Update**:
It's important to mention that this works well most of the time, 98% of the time and bulk inserting properly. Just 2% of the time, some rows already exist that will cause the bulk insert to fail.

What we need: we need to "ignore" those rows if exist

What we do: Data transfer of source database to dest db. It's not a full transfer. We transfer a subset of the source data. The dest db is NOT empty. It already contains data. So update is NOT an option.  We need to insert if not exists.

There are around 30 tables that we do bulk insert from source to dest db. So we have a generic function that does field mapping, bulk inserting, etc... it's the same function that handles all these tables.

Again, what we need: We are using SqlBulkCopy.WriteToServer and we need to "**ignore**" rows if they exist. Thanks

Comment: You can't you have to put them into a temp table and then reconcile/update. [See Answer Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4846770/4688413)

Comment: Consider using this library, I found it by chance, and it has been very helpful https://www.nuget.org/packages/SqlBulkTools.NetStandard/ namely `.BulkInsertOrUpdate()`

Comment: @WardenUnleashed Not feasible when inserting millions of records

Comment: Sure it's feasible.  Millions of rows isn't that much, and even if it's problematic for your environment, you can do so in smaller batches.

Comment: @anastaciu `BulkInsertOrUpdate` bulk inserts into a temp table and then [uses a `merge` statement](https://github.com/tiagorosendo/SqlBulkTools/blob/master/SqlBulkTools.NetStandard/BulkOperations/BulkInsertOrUpdate.cs#L396) to transfer the data into the target table. Merge statements can be a source of annoyance due to performance issues and [they still have a number of open bugs](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3074/use-caution-with-sql-servers-merge-statement/).

Comment: @AlwaysLearning yes, that's about right, I wasn't aware of those problems though, I use this to update a table with nearly 800000 entries, and it's heavily updated due to distance recalculations and never spoted any problems, and it's been super fast, just lucky I guess, thanks for the info...

Comment: Since we're offering solutions outside of the class OP asked about, I'll just throw out there that an alternative that could maximize performance & accomplish his goals is writing the insert code in SQL. For example a stored procedure that takes in a user defined table type parameter, and within the procedure  you do an outer join between your `dbo.Pharmacy` table and the table parameter to exclude any matches (rows that exist in your `dbo.Pharmacy` table). With proper indexing this could be a performant solution, but I understand is quite far off programmatically from OP's original direction.

Comment: A temp table with the correct indexing should be pretty fast even for large numbers of rows

Comment: Thanks everyone! Let's forget about the temp table for a second. We do not want to do any update if the record exists. Just ignore it when exists, insert it if not exists. That's what we need. I will update the original question and explain what we do and what we need.

Comment: @Khodr SqlBulkCopy as the name suggest is for copying (inserting) bulk records and it cannot perform update operation. Hence comes Table Valued Parameter to the rescue, which allows us to pass multiple records using a DataTable to a Stored Procedure where we can do the processing.

Answer (score 0):

SqlBulkCopy as the name suggest is for copying (inserting) bulk records and it cannot perform update operation. Hence comes Table Valued Parameter to the rescue, which allows us to pass multiple records using a DataTable to a Stored Procedure where we can do the processing...

SQL Server 2008(or higher) came up with a nice function called MERGE, which allows to perform INSERT operation when records are not present and UPDATE when records are present in the table.

You can create a User Defined Table Type in SQL Server

Finally the following similar kind of stored procedure is created which will accept the whole DataTable as parameter and then will insert all records into the table that are not present in the table and the one that already exists will be updated.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[Update_Pharmacy]
      @tblCustomers CustomerType READONLY
AS
BEGIN
      SET NOCOUNT ON;
 
      MERGE INTO Customers c1
      USING @tblCustomers c2
      ON c1.CustomerId=c2.Id
      WHEN MATCHED THEN
      UPDATE SET c1.Name = c2.Name
            ,c1.Country = c2.Country
      WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
      INSERT VALUES(c2.Id, c2.Name, c2.Country);
END
```

The performance will be less as Bulk Copy Utlity but somehow it is one of option i have used while working on a reporting database from realtime DB.